# sorting UITableView into sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm new to swift & Xcode (teaching myself via tutorials and stackoverflow). I've written some code that adds places to a list in a TableView and now I am trying to sort that list of places into sections.

Specifically, I have a ViewController where I input name, neighborhood and friend (all strings) and this adds a Place to the bottom of my TableView.

I want to group this list of places by neighborhood, and display all the places in the same neighborhood together in a section, using the neighborhood string as the section header.

I'm close, but I'm not indexing my sections correctly. indexPath.section I believe is what I'm missing..

So far I have this code in my TableViewController:

```
// MARK: Properties

var places = [Place]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()

    // Load any saved places, otherwise load sample data.
    if let savedPlaces = loadPlaces() {
        places += savedPlaces
    }

    else {
        // Load the sample data.
        loadSamplePlaces()
    }

    // Sort by neighborhood
    places.sortInPlace { (place1, place2) -> Bool in
        return place1.neighborhood < place2.neighborhood
    }
}

// MARK: Getting Count, Number and Name of Neighborhoods
func getCountForNeighborhood(neighborhood:String) -> Int {
    return places.filter { (place) -> Bool in
        return place.neighborhood == neighborhood
    }.count
}

func getNumberOfNeighborhoods() -> Int {
    var neighborhoodCount = 0
    var neighborhoodPrev = "Not a real neighborhood"
    for place in places {
        if place.neighborhood != neighborhoodPrev {
            neighborhoodCount += 1
        }
        neighborhoodPrev = place.neighborhood
    }
    return neighborhoodCount
}

func getNeighborhoodForSection(section:Int) -> String {
    var previousNeighborhood:String = "Not a real neighborhood"
    var currentIndex = -1

    for place in places {

        if(place.neighborhood != previousNeighborhood) {
            currentIndex += 1
        }
        if(currentIndex == section){
            return place.neighborhood
        }
        previousNeighborhood = place.neighborhood
    }

    return "Unknown"
}

func loadSamplePlaces() {

    let place1 = Place(name: "Motorino", neighborhood: "East Village", friend: "Maggles")!
    let place2 = Place(name: "Bar Primi", neighborhood: "Lower East Side", friend: "Em")!
    let place3 = Place(name: "El Carino", neighborhood: "Williamsburg", friend: "Ruby")!

    places += [place1, place2, place3]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //alter this for To Try, Been To sections =2
    return getNumberOfNeighborhoods()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    let neighborhood = getNeighborhoodForSection(section)
    return getCountForNeighborhood(neighborhood)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "PlaceTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlaceTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate place for the data source layout.

    let place = places[indexPath.row]

    cell.placeLabel.text = place.name
    cell.neighborhoodLabel.text = place.neighborhood
    cell.friendLabel.text = place.friend

    return cell
}

//Add section headers
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return getNeighborhoodForSection(section)

}
```

I'm fairly certain it's an issue with my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I think I'm missing some code to properly index the data into sections...

Current build displays [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mess with sections.

In method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` you're taking data from the places array based on the row of the indexPath.
But you don't "talk" about sections at all. That's why you tell the data source delegate to take the data of those 2 place objects regardless of the section it's asking you.
You've made a data structure in a relational style like this:

```
neighbourhood1 - place1
neighbourhood1 - place2
neighbourhood2 - place3
neighbourhood2 - place4
neighbourhood3 - place5
neighbourhood3 - place6
```

And believe me, it's really hard to interface this data structure with the `UITableView` data source concept, cause it's really hard to determine the section index from the single data.
Try to arrange your data in a tree like this:

```
neighbourhood1:
 - place1
 - place2
neighbourhood2:
 - place3
 - place4
neighbourhood3:
 - place5
 - place6
```

In an array of arrays, and then it will be simple, cause the indexPath pair (section, row) will match the indexes of your `places[section][row]`:

```
neighbourhood1: (section 0)
 - place1 (path 0.0)
 - place2 (path 0.1)
neighbourhood2: (section 1)
 - place3 (path 1.0)
 - place4 (path 1.1)
neighbourhood3: (section 2)
 - place5 (path 2.0)
 - place6 (path 2.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do concur with the other answer: this will be easier if your store your data in a two-dimensional array organized by neighborhood first, then place second, then access the data as:

```
let place = places[indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

However, to your specific questions and current code, I see two things here. First, your sample data has a single item per neighborhood, but your table is showing two rows per neighborhood. That indicates that your `numberOfRowsInSection` function is returning 2 when we expect it to be 1. Make sure your `getNeighborhoodForSection` is returning the right section. Then look at why `getCountForNeighborhood` isn't returning 1 for each section. (As an aside, you probably already know this, but `getNeighborhoodForSection` assumes your data is always sorted by neighborhood. If you insert a new neighborhood out of order, you'll run into problems).

Second, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you always pull data by the `indexPath.row` number. When you enter this function for each neighborhood, the `indexPath.row` number will always restart at 0 for each section (neighborhood). And therefore you'll pull the 1st item out of `places` (Motorino) for the first row in every section. That's why you see the same list of places repeated in each section.

Once you have the right number of rows per neighborhood, In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to:

1. Get the neighborhood for index.section using your `getNeighborhoodForSection(index.section);`
2. Search through `places` until you find that neighborhood and save the index of the starting point, which I'll call `neighborHoodStartIndex`
3. `let place = places[neighborHoodStartIndex + indexPath.row]`

For debugging purposes, I'd suggest making a different number of sample places in each neighborhood. It'll be a little easier to spot problem patterns when you expect different numbers of rows in each section.